# Expected value for a function with a normal distributed random variable

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value

I have a random variable $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ and a function $5x^2 + 2x$. How can I calculate $E(g(x))$ ?

I have two ideas, altough I'm not sure which one is right:

- $E(g(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x) f_X(x) dx\\ =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 5x^2 + 2x\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{ -\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2 }$
- The function above just computes the weighted average of the values that
  $g(x)$ can take on for different values of x. The normal distrubution is symmetric, so $E[g(x)] = 5 \mu^2 + 2\mu$

Sorry if the question might sound stupid, I don't have a statistics background.

Comment: Var(x) = E(x^2) - E(x)^2

Comment: Expectation is 'linear': For constants $c,d$ and random variables $X,Y$, we have $E[cX+dY]=cE[X]+dE[Y]$ whenever all expectations exist.// Note that $E[X^2]$ *does not* equal $(E[X])^2$ for a non-constant variable $X$.

Comment: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 5x^2 + 2x\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{ -\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2 }$ should be $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (5x^2 + 2x)\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{ -\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2 },$ which turns into two terms--one trivial and one requiring a bit of throught. // What does symmetry have to do with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$E[g(x)] = E[5x^2+2x] = 5E[x^2] + 2E[x]$.

$E[x^2] = var(x) + E(x)^2 = \sigma^{2} + \mu^{2}$.

Hence $E[g(x)] = 5(\sigma^2 + \mu^2) + 2\mu$.

Read for *Delta method* for more general cases.

---

Edit) Sorry for the sign. For the $E[x^2]$, I changed the sign from (-) to (+) and henceforth.

When $g(\cdot)$ is not linear (for the $N(\cdot, \cdot)$, higher order moments are "known", but for general cases they are not)  or X is non-normal, then you may apply delta method in order to get distribution of $g(x)$.

Comment: What 'Delta method' in this context?

Comment: No, this is wrong (a $+$ sign has changed to a $-$ sign);  _cf._ comment by @JesperHybel on main question. for the correct formula.

Comment: Right general idea. Checking results for a special case by simulation.

Answer (score 0):

Comment: Checking by simulation, for the special case $\mu = 25, \sigma = 3.$

```
set.seed(2019)
mu = 25;  sg = 3
x = rnorm(10^7, mu, sg)

y = 5*x^2 + 2*x
> mean(y)
[1] 3220.226   # aprx answ
2*sd(y)/sqrt(10^7)
[1] 0.4798108  # 95% margin of simulation error

5*(sg^2 - mu^2) + 2*mu
[1] -3030      # doesn't match aprx answ
5*(sg^2 + mu^2) + 2*mu
[1] 3220       # seems to match aprx answ
```

@crux26: Looks as if @DilipSarwate is right; you have a wrong
sign. Please edit your answer.